# How can a Jersey InjectableProvider depend on the AbstractMethod of the resource?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, jersey, jersey-1.0

I have a `ResourceFilterFactory` that returns a `ContainerRequestFilter` if an annotation is present on the `AbstractMethod`.

The filter reads a cookie or API key and checks that it is still valid, and sets a property on the request. The check is expensive, so I only want it to occur when the annotation is present.

I want to inject the resulting object into my resource, but it seems that injection happens before `ResourceFilterFactory` filters are applied. If I add the filter to the `ResourceConfig` as a `PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS`, then it happens before the injection, but it does not have access to the `AbstractMethod`.

How do I bridge the gap, so that the filter is applied and the field is injected only if the method has the annotation?

My code looks something like this. `AuthFilter` is called after `UserIdProvider`, so `c.getProperties().get(USER_ID_PROPERTY)` is always `null`.

```
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    Integer userId = …; // expensive lookup
    request.getProperties().set(USER_ID_PROPERTY, userId);
    return request;
  }
}

public class AuthFilterFactory implements ResourceFilterFactory {
  // …
  public List<ResourceFilter> create(AbstractMethod am) {
    if (am.isAnnotationPresent(RequireAuth.class) || am.getResource().isAnnotationPresent(RequireAuth.class)) {
      return Collections.singletonList(new ResourceFilter() {
        public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {
          return authFilter;
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

InjectableProvider:

```
@Provider
public class UserIdProvider implements InjectableProvider<UserId, Parameter> {
  public ComponentScope getScope() {
    return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
  }

  public Injectable<? extends Object> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, UserId a, final Parameter t) {
    return new AbstractHttpContextInjectable<Integer>() {
      public Integer getValue(HttpContext c) {
        return (Integer) c.getProperties().get(USER_ID_PROPERTY);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Resource:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {
  @UserId
  Integer userId;

  // userId should only be set on this method
  @GET
  @RequireAuth
  public UserDetails get() {
    // …
  }

  // the auth filter should not be called for this method
  @POST
  @Path("/login")
  public String login() {
    // …
  }
}
```

Comment: So you need a filter that runs after the request has been matched, but before the matched resources have been instantiated. This isn't possible with Jersey 1.x afaik, not sure about Jersey 2.x